# What does bind do on an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

EXAMPLE "BIND"  from ReactJS code. I have never used bind and not sure what it does on an ajax call like in the code below.

```
React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () {
        $.get(this.props.url, function (data) {
            this.setState(data);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function () {
        return <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't specifically do anything to ajax calls, it binds the this-value for any function it's used on.
From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

A quick example

```
function doStuff() {
    console.log(this); // would print "hello kitty"
}

var fn = doStuff.bind('Hello Kitty'); // set "this", then return new function

fn(); // call with given "this" value
```

The code in the question simple sets the `this` value inside the `$.get` functions callback, to the same `this` value as `componentWillMount()`